# Get children of a tree structure

Tags: c#, tree, parent-child

```
public JsonResult GetFolderChildren(int id, List<string> res)
    {
            List<tblFolders> folders = (from x in db.tblFolders
                                where x.folderParent == id
                                select x).ToList();
            foreach (var f in folders)
            {
                res.Add("FOLDER_" + f.id.ToString());
            }
            foreach (var r in res)
            {
                GetFolderChildren(int.Parse(r.Replace("FOLDER_", "")), res);
            }

        return Json(res, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
```

But it doesn't work. A folder can have children, their children can have other children etc.
My code just gives me the first children.

Comment: So you want the leaf folders? Then I have a solution, or do you want the leafs of the tree, which are the files.

Comment: @MrFox No, I want all the children, grandchildren etc. of a folder.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what language that is, but if I had to guess, it's because you're calling "GetFolderChildren" on the files rather than the folders.  You probably mean to do the inverse, which is to say, call "GetFolderChildren" for each folder and simply add each resource present.

Also, I would advise against returning something if you're not going to use it.  The effect seems to be accomplished modifying the list.  If you need the last call to return a JsonResult object, then have two methods, the parent calling the inner method with the parent returning the JsonResult object (avoiding unnecessary performance loss).